# Constraining a Search's context

Tags: google-search

## GOAL

A word, like 'class' can have different meaning \ nuances depending on the context of how it is used.

I would like to understand how to constrain a Google search on a keyword so that it returns results in a *constrained context*.  What I mean by this is that if search on the word **classes**, I would like to only see the results associated with C programming.  I do not want results associated with educational classes or groups of people.

Other examples of constrained contexts could include LINUX, Ubuntu, OSX, Windows 10, Python, etc.

Google enables users to constrain a search within a website using the syntax:

```
site:fooo.com   classes  -education
```

In the example of above Google will search the website fooo.com for the word classes and strike results with the term education

## QUESTION

What is the syntax to search Google with the constrained context as defined above?

Bonus points if there is a better (standard) term for 'constrained context'

Comment: What's wrong with "C programming classes"?

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to find any indication that Google supports this in a direct fashion; your best bet is to add additional related search terms that will narrow the context - for your example, I might include such additional terms as **inheritance**, **definition**, **"virtual method"** (with the quotes), and so on - you will know best what you are trying to find; choose your search terms accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Google Search doesn't include a syntac to constrain result by context, instead it rank the results considering several factors including the user search history.

Considering the above you could start by searching

```
C programming class
```

Then add `-` below the terms that you want o exclude, i.e. course

```
C programming class -course
```

And so on